# css media query is not functioning properly

Tags: css

I am trying to make a physician website,everything worked well but 
Media queries are not working, I tried several times but I don't know why it's not working. 
Here's the codepen link:
https://codepen.io/Razu381/pen/XQJVzg

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

body{
    font-size: 15px;
}

.slide-text h4{
    font-size: 25px;
}

.slide-text p{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the code you provided was that you needed another set of closing brackets.

````
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) { <- start of the media query

body{
    font-size: 15px;
}

.slide-text h4{
    font-size: 25px;
}

.slide-text p{
    font-size: 16px;
}<- end of slide text p

<- no end of the media query```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should work as you expect it to.

```
@media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 480px) {

    body{
        font-size: 15px;
        }

        .slide-text h4{
            font-size: 25px;
         }

        .slide-text p{
                font-size: 16px;
        }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with mine???

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It's a good idea when answering to add a small description as to how the code in your answer will resolve the the problem _ Just one or two sentences explanation is usually enough : )

Answer (score 0):

Its syntax-error You are missing a }.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

  body{
      font-size: 15px;
  }

  .slide-text h4{
      font-size: 25px;
  }

  .slide-text p{
      font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the } (closing bracket) at the last. code will work after adding the closing bracket.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

     body{
        font-size: 15px;
     }

     .slide-text h4{
        font-size: 25px;
     }

     .slide-text p{
        font-size: 16px;
     }
}
```